# Grouping by row value while aggregating total value of other cell value

Tags: r, aggregate, grouping

I have a data frame that looks something like this

```
user booking_date origin destination  price  sale_channel
1 user5   2018-11-01    MAD         PMI  58.20        online
2 user7   2018-11-01    DUB         MAD 147.50        online
3 user4   2018-11-02    TFS         MAD  24.05        online
4 user7   2018-11-01    LPA         MAD  37.30   call center
5 user1   2018-11-01    AMS         MAD 149.74 travel agency
6 user1   2018-11-01    MAD         PMI  19.95        online
```

Now I want to:

1. Filter by a specific date (2018-11-02) which I've done by

```
df <- df[df$booking_date == '2018-11-02',]
```

2. Group by the user and sum u their total spending on tickets.

I've tried a couple of approaches using group_by or aggregate but all I managed to get was an additional column but not grouping or aggregating the value per user.

3. My final output would idealy by something enabling me to extract the 10 users that spend the most on tickets like this for example:

```
'user1' 'user10' 'user 7' etc.
```

**Example Data**

```
structure(list(user = c("user4", "user5", "user3", "user10", 
"user1", "user2", "user7", "user6", "user5", "user6", "user6", 
"user7", "user1", "user7", "user4", "user4", "user1", "user7", 
"user7", "user8", "user4", "user10", "user4", "user8", "user3", 
"user9", "user5", "user2", "user5", "user3", "user3", "user9", 
"user6", "user10", "user9", "user5", "user3", "user5", "user7", 
"user9", "user2", "user2", "user7", "user10", "user7", "user3", 
"user1", "user2", "user8", "user6", "user6", "user10", "user4", 
"user7", "user4", "user1", "user4", "user2", "user1", "user7", 
"user5", "user4", "user4", "user7", "user10"), booking_date = structure(c(17837, 
17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 
17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 
17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 
17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 
17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 
17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 
17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 17837, 
17837), class = "Date"), origin = c("TFS", "MAD", "TFN", "MAD", 
"LYS", "LPA", "MAD", "MAD", "AMS", "MAD", "MAD", "MAD", "MAD", 
"LPA", "MAD", "MAD", "MAD", "TXL", "MAD", "MAD", "TXL", "TXL", 
"TFS", "MAD", "NAP", "TFS", "PMI", "TLS", "TFS", "NTE", "AMS", 
"FUE", "TFN", "CPH", "TFN", "MAD", "SVQ", "SCQ", "SVQ", "MAD", 
"PMI", "MAD", "PMI", "MAD", "MAD", "MAD", "MAD", "MAD", "SVQ", 
"NCE", "CDG", "MAD", "MAD", "MAD", "MAD", "MAD", "TFN", "LGW", 
"LGW", "MAD", "TFN", "MAD", "RNS", "AGP", "CDG"), destination = c("MAD", 
"DUB", "MAD", "TFS", "MAD", "MAD", "NAP", "TLS", "MAD", "SCQ", 
"LPA", "TFN", "TXL", "MAD", "TFN", "SVQ", "ACE", "MAD", "TLS", 
"SCQ", "MAD", "MAD", "MAD", "LPA", "MAD", "MAD", "MAD", "MAD", 
"MAD", "MAD", "MAD", "MAD", "MAD", "MAD", "MAD", "CAG", "MAD", 
"MAD", "MAD", "LPA", "MAD", "CDG", "MAD", "LPA", "TFS", "TFN", 
"PMI", "NAP", "MAD", "MAD", "MAD", "LPA", "LGW", "LPA", "CDG", 
"SPC", "MAD", "MAD", "MAD", "SCQ", "MAD", "SVQ", "MAD", "MAD", 
"MAD"), price = c(24.0499992371, 41.5400009155, 251.199996948, 
15.6000003815, 44.0099983215, 73.8499984741, 115.470001221, 69.4400024414, 
81.3899993896, 15.2399997711, 41.1199989319, 274.559997559, 150, 
29.3199996948, 332.440002441, 94.9100036621, 97.9800033569, 55.1199989319, 
81.7399978638, 4.86000013351, 39.0299987793, 53.6300010681, 39.3199996948, 
114.559997559, 65.4000015259, 96.2900009155, 41.75, 28.9099998474, 
25.1900005341, 14, 50.3100013733, 47.2999992371, 53.8199996948, 
91.3199996948, 77.6800003052, 17.8099994659, 96.5400009155, 27.6900005341, 
34.1399993896, 34.3300018311, 15.5600004196, 158.449996948, 45.2999992371, 
36.8100013733, 50.6800003052, 62.9000015259, 13.7399997711, 49.4399986267, 
66.1100006104, 95.4400024414, 41.8400001526, 69.8300018311, 60.6599998474, 
34.3300018311, 97.1399993896, 84.3099975586, 25.8099994659, 185.899993896, 
34.8899993896, 304.380004883, 15.1300001144, 29.1399993896, 133.529998779, 
208.910003662, 152.960006714), sale_channel = c("online", "online", 
"travel agency", "online", "online", "online", "travel agency", 
"online", "travel agency", "travel agency", "travel agency", 
"online", "travel agency", "online", "online", "travel agency", 
"online", "travel agency", "travel agency", "call center", "online", 
"online", "online", "travel agency", "travel agency", "travel agency", 
"online", "online", "online", "online", "online", "travel agency", 
"travel agency", "online", "travel agency", "call center", "online", 
"travel agency", "online", "online", "travel agency", "travel agency", 
"online", "travel agency", "online", "online", "online", "travel agency", 
"online", "travel agency", "travel agency", "online", "online", 
"online", "online", "online", "online", "online", "online", "travel agency", 
"travel agency", "travel agency", "online", "travel agency", 
"online"), total = c(876.0300006858, 250.5000009536, 540.3500022886, 
420.1500110628, 424.9299983977, 512.1099882118, 1233.9500045785, 
316.9000034332, 250.5000009536, 316.9000034332, 316.9000034332, 
1233.9500045785, 424.9299983977, 1233.9500045785, 876.0300006858, 
876.0300006858, 424.9299983977, 1233.9500045785, 1233.9500045785, 
185.52999830291, 876.0300006858, 420.1500110628, 876.0300006858, 
185.52999830291, 540.3500022886, 255.6000022889, 250.5000009536, 
512.1099882118, 250.5000009536, 540.3500022886, 540.3500022886, 
255.6000022889, 316.9000034332, 420.1500110628, 255.6000022889, 
250.5000009536, 540.3500022886, 250.5000009536, 1233.9500045785, 
255.6000022889, 512.1099882118, 512.1099882118, 1233.9500045785, 
420.1500110628, 1233.9500045785, 540.3500022886, 424.9299983977, 
512.1099882118, 185.52999830291, 316.9000034332, 316.9000034332, 
420.1500110628, 876.0300006858, 1233.9500045785, 876.0300006858, 
424.9299983977, 876.0300006858, 512.1099882118, 424.9299983977, 
1233.9500045785, 250.5000009536, 876.0300006858, 876.0300006858, 
1233.9500045785, 420.1500110628)), row.names = c(3L, 
26L, 37L, 42L, 48L, 82L, 89L, 100L, 112L, 124L, 133L, 144L, 148L, 
150L, 166L, 167L, 173L, 182L, 217L, 243L, 259L, 285L, 300L, 304L, 
306L, 336L, 341L, 366L, 388L, 397L, 413L, 417L, 423L, 452L, 457L, 
473L, 474L, 478L, 482L, 483L, 486L, 496L, 499L, 504L, 510L, 513L, 
529L, 531L, 558L, 605L, 615L, 628L, 629L, 664L, 669L, 672L, 684L, 
722L, 730L, 752L, 766L, 767L, 779L, 804L, 819L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Any recommendations on how to approach this?

Edit:
Final Solution

```
df <- df[df$booking_date == '2018-11-02',]
total <- aggregate(price ~ user, df, sum)
top_10 <- total[order(total$price, decreasing = T), ]
top_10[1:5, 1]
```

That gives me

```
"user7" "user4" "user3" "user2" "user1"
```

Comment: try `df$total <- ave(df$price, df$user, FUN = sum)`.

Comment: thanks, goes into the right direction, but how do I now actually group by the user or at least retreive the n number of biggest spenders?

Comment: Please provide [a minimal reproducible data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/10068985) and your expected output. You can produce a example data or `dput()` part of your real data.

Comment: I edited my initial question, the desired output is under point 3

Comment: `aggregate(price ~ user, df, sum)` solve your question? You just need to sort the price to see who spends the most.

Comment: Thanks, but only sort of. I tried both using ```order()``` and ```sort()``` to get to the final solution. But I still don't manage to display both columns price and users sorted by price decreasing or just the users sorted decreasing by the values in thee prices column...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
total <- aggregate(price ~ user, df, sum)
total[order(total$price, decreasing = T), ]
```

or

```
dplyr::arrange(total, desc(price))
```

or

```
sort(tapply(df$price, df$user, sum), decreasing = T)
```

Comment: That does the trick, I'll post my final solution in the original question. I assume there is a more elegant way but it works, thanks!